# How do I dynamically load third party libraries that only offer a CDN in an Angular 7 App?

Tags: javascript, angular, cdn

I am trying to download the content of a javascript file from a CDN imperatively within a typescript file so that I can make use of it in the correct lifecycle hooks, and so that I can ensure it is only downloaded when it is first needed.

For example the googleCDN to download Jquery:

I do not want to add the library src to my index.html page, and I do not want to add it to my angular.json configuration file because I do not want to use this library in many places in my app, and so I do not want to always force my users to download it.

I have been experimenting with the HttpClient.JsonP method because the CDN server I am trying to request the library from is enforcing CORS, however, I believe that because the response is not JSON, rather a function, it doesn't work.

example code:

```
load<T = any>(): Observable<T> {
    return this.http
        .jsonp(
            'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js',
            'callback'
        ) as Observable<T>;
}
```

with the error:

```
"JSONP injected script did not invoke callback."
```

That error makes sense I think because the response is not JSON and is not wrapped in a function like a browser expects.

I am now trying a similar technique as here:
https://gist.github.com/zainzafar90/1f58a4a04ac17fcf8e7424a053620822#file-dynamic-script-loader-service-ts

But I really don't like this as I believe I will have to augment a global variable with this, although I don't know how as of yet.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @MikeJuneBugCaptain I am using Angular 7